# Calculate ROC curve with true positive rate and false negative rate

Tags: roc

I have a classifier in which I only cross individuals with themselves. So all I can get is TPR (true positive rate) and FNR (false negative rate). How could I draw the ROC curve with these values? And calculate the EER?

This is my ROC curve with TP and FN.

[image]

Comment: What about 1-FNR?

Comment: @StudentT Why 1-FNR? What is this exactly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity